# Gmail suddenly not showing recipient names in "Sent" folder

Tags: gmail

The Sent folders in Gmail on both my Galaxy phone and my Nexus tablet are suddenly showing only "me" as the sender.

I want to quickly see who I sent them to without having to open every one to look at the details.

Is it a bug? Otherwise, is it possible to fix/workaround this?

Comment: Just a curiosity check, is it still an issue? I just checked my Gmail app (v.2022.01.09) on Pixel 3a and it's showing "To:" in the Sent folder.

Answer (score 2):

It is a known issue. You can use the app feedback to send a report to Google. To my knowledge, there is no fix. You will just have to live with it until they fix it, which considering the post date on some of the places that others have complained, it might not get fixed anytime soon.

Other places this issue has been posted at:

[Sent folder showing sender instead of recipient - 9/12/18](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/gwGwhNHYmC0/gvv4qHQcAwAJ)

[Sent Items Show Sender Not Recipient In Sent Folder - 3/17/17](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/n1NUD4ybe_I/l86CJV04BQAJ)

[Showing recipient name in the sent label/folder in Gmail on Android - 2/4/14](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/W7aHMLzFE_8/C6sGu9YZPZgJ)

Comment: Do you know what the version of Gmail you were using before it stopped?

Comment: All I can do it point out what other people are experiencing, which is the same problem as you, dating back to at least 2014, maybe even further. Yes, it is a dumb design that should be fixed, but Google is Google, and they will not get to it fast.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no fix. If you find one, then please post it here, as I am sure everyone else who has asked will want to know the answer. Otherwise, you will just have to live with it and send feedback, or revert back to the old build of Gmail that had that feature, and send feedback.

Comment: Hey, CodeMonkey, I'm intrigued to see/hear your reference to the "old build".

Any idea what version/year that was?

Comment: I have no idea. That is why I was asking you, who had the version that apparently had the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Very annoying problem. I noticed it recently. Until Google fix it, one solution is to use another mailbox company who isn't plagued by this problem (Yahoo, for instance) and switch your gmail account there. Not perfect but if enough people do it, maybe Google will start working on it.

Comment: Please don't suggest Yahoo, a company known to have exposed BILLIONS of records through security lapses, as a substitute.

Comment: I thought I read somewhere...recently, like in Jan/Feb 2020-ish, that there IS a cure and that it had something to do with going into Gmail settings and making all associated accounts "aliases"....(or NOT making them aliases!?!?)
Call me crazy, but has anyone else seen that reference?